# Solve playstore issue; requesting for app access

Tags: android, google-play

Google recently removed my app from the App Store. I was asked to provide login access to my app for them to review the app "In app experience issue".

My App is using phone number authentication, I believe if Google wants to access my app they can login with any phone number, provide the authentication code and gain access. But I was asked to provide the login details, the problem is if I give Google just any registered phone number, it will still ask for a phone authentication code to login.

How can I add a default phone number that will not ask to provide authentication code tat will login the user. My app is built with android studio and firebase as backend.

Or is there anyway I can provide google with access to my app, that wont request authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You should make one number (preferably a phone number you own) always take the same authentication code (OTP).

ideally this should be done from backend, but if it easier for you, you can make it hard coded into your app, like the following pseudo code:

```
if(phoneNumber == 001xxxxxxxxx)
then if(userInputOTP == 1234) then isOTPCorrect = true
```